# Image not displaying in Firefox only on one computer

Tags: image

I built a fairly simple site, and all seems to be working fine, except one photo is showing up on almost every device/different computer I've looked at it on, except for one computer (in Firefox)!!! Does anyone know why a photo would show up for the majority of people, but wouldn't display on one computer??? There is no "broken path" icon that shows up for this person-- the image simply isn't there. Does this have anything to do with their browser settings maybe? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried cleaning cache? Can you see the image tag when inspecting element in firefox in that computer? Or any errors in console?

Comment: The computer that's posing the problem is actually near another city, and I'm not sure that person knows how to inspect element, but I can walk them through it..

Comment: Did you try out your site on another web browser on PC with troubles?

Comment: Yes-- it's worked fine on PC's and Macs, across browsers. Of course, there's a little bit of variation with the display across browsers, but nothing major.